# Нужна ли запятая перед союзом "как"? (2)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как

> У нас вы найдете запасные детали и аксессуары для коммерческого
>   транспорта и спецтехники в наличии от европейских поставщиков, которые
>   давно зарекомендовали себя как лучшие производители в своем сегменте.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая не нужна. Объясняется это тем что слово *как* употреблено в значении *в качестве*.

> 3. Употр. для присоединения оборотов, имеющих оттенок сравнения; в качестве кого-, чего-л., будучи кем-, чем-л. *Советую как друг быть осмотрительнее* ([Грамота](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA))

--

> Запятая перед "как" не ставится в 6 случаях:
>   1.В значении - в качестве
>   Примеры: *Пьесу восприняли как призыв к борьбе*. (Восприняли в качестве призыва к борьбе) ([Best-Language](https://best-language.ru/zapjataja-pered-kak-ne-stavitsja))

--

> § 90. Обороты со сравнительными союзами (частицами) как, словно, будто, точно, как будто, что не выделяются запятыми в следующих случаях:
>   б) при передаче значения «в качестве» (оборот является частью сказуемого): Сергей Лазо был прислан комитетом как главнокомандующий (Фад.); ...Тамара Ивановна поняла этот голос как посланное ей вдогонку прощание (Расп.); ([Лопатин](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=125#pp125))

Дополнение. Слова "в наличие" здесь ни к месту. Замените их синонимом *имеется* и посмотрите, что получится.

> [НАЛИЧИЕ](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5), -я; ср. Офиц. Присутствие, существование. Выявить н. пушных зверей в районе озера. <В наличии, в функц. сказ. Есть, имеется, налицо. Весь инвентарь в наличии Оружия в наличии не имелось.

Answer (score 1):

У нас вы найдете запасные детали и аксессуары для коммерческого транспорта и спецтехники от европейских поставщиков, которые давно **зарекомендовали себя как лучшие производители в своем сегменте.**

Итак, запятой нет.

**Не можем мы обособить этот оборот**, так как  по смыслу он тесно связан со сказуемым. Это означает, что **семантика глагола *зарекомендовать* не является выраженной  без зависимого слова.**

Например: Поставщики зарекомендовали себя (как?) ― хорошо, отлично, превосходно; как лучшие производители, в качестве лучших производителей.

В данном случае оборот **не входит в состав сказуемого**, но тесно связан со сказуемым и поэтому не обособляется.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая не нужна.

> Не обособляются обороты с союзом КАК в пяти случаях:
>
> 3. Если оборот с союзом КАК входит в состав сказуемого и предложение без такого оборота не имеет законченного смысла, например: *Она держится как хозяйка;*
>
> ([Грамота.ру](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_183))

Данное предложение как раз такой случай.